# first value in the list is equal to the first value in the other list. python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, list, arraylist, sublist

so imagine I had a sublist

```
exList = [
    ['green', 'apple', 'NO'],
    ['red','apple','nO'],
    ['red','watermellon','no'],
    ['yellow','honeymellon','yes']
]
```

so I want to check if the first value in the list is equal to the first value in the other list.

so exlist is a sublist, it has 4 different list. So i want to check the first value in the first list and check if it's equal to any other value in the other list. So Green is the first value and green is not used  in the other list so it should return False. But if green was used in the other lists it should return True.

```
for i in exList:
    if i+1[1] == i-[1]:
        print True
```

how can i do this?

Comment: You want to check what?

Comment: so exlist is a sublist, it has 4 different list. So i want to check the first value in the first list and check if it's equal to any other value in the other list. So Green is the first value and green is not used  in the other list so it should return False. But if green was used in the other lists it should return True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand your request you want to check if the first value for the first list in exList exists in each of the remaining lists? If so you could use list comprehension as follows:

```
check = [True if (exList[0][0] in subList) else False for subList in exList[1:]]
```

or you can do this in a loop if you don't understand list comprehension:

```
check = []
checkItem = exList[0][0] #Pulls the value for the first item in the first list of exList
for i in range(1,len(exList)): #Starts at 1 to skip the first list in exList
  check.append(checkItem in exList[i])
print check
```

And if you need to loop over each item in the first list to check:

```
for eachListItem in exList[0]:
  print "Search Text: %s" % (eachListItem)
  curCheck = [True if (eachListItem in subList) else False for subList in exList[1:]]
  print "Search Results: %s" % (True in curCheck)
```

Note: None of this would account for spaces in a string or mismatched cases (I.E. NO and No are two different values and would return false. Similarly "No " and "No" are different)

Comment: how would i make it ignore cases? for the second one as that one is easily to understand

Comment: I would recommend looking into the `re` module for complex comparisons.  I made an example that you can reference here: https://repl.it/FTcV/4